# HC-05 master and slave

Tags: serial

I have a silly question that came to my mind
when communicating between HC-05 and A smartphone, the smartphone is considered as the master,
and the HC-05 is considered a slave.
master will send data to the slave and then the slave will send these data to the MCU.
my question here is that, what is the MCU considered if it is not a master or slave?
if I got something wrong, I'll be glad if you correct it for me.
thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "not a master or a slave"? Bluetooth always has a master and a slave. When should the HC-05 ever be none of that?

Comment: HC-05 <=> MCU is a serial connection without any master/slave protocol, handshake or whatever.

Comment: if MCU is in serial communication with HC-05, then both of them are considered a slave ? @chrisl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misconception about the interfaces involved. Actually we have 2 different interfaces here: Bluetooth and Serial (UART). The HC-05 is a Bluetooth Serial bridge.

The Bluetooth interface has a fixed concept of master and slave. Every connection needs to have only 1 single master. This concept applies only to the communication between HC-05 and the smartphone. It has nothing to do with the MCU itself, because the MCU does not do any Bluetooth communication.

The second interface is the Serial (UART) interface between the HC-05 and the MCU. For this interface there is no concept of master/slave, because it is not needed. Either of them can send independently on their corresponding TX pin and can receive on their RX pin.

These are two totally independent and different communication interfaces. The HC-05 just forwards data between the interfaces.

Comment: very clear now thank you !